# Why would "infer" in conditional type change the return type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I was playing with conditional types and stubbled upon this problem :

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
type Foo = FormGroup<{ title: FormControl<string> }>
type Bar = FormGroup<{ title2: FormControl<string>; }>;

type Baz = Foo | Bar extends FormGroup<infer U> ? 'ok ' : 'nok'; // NOK
//   ^?
type Baz2 = Foo | Bar extends FormGroup ? 'ok ' : 'nok'; // OK
//   ^?
```

Why would the presence of `infer` change the return type here ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMWiA4lCBXMAaFNAYQgDsYsAbAgQQCMBnCgQwGMYTyq4BfOAMywg4AcgACzUgHNslZlAD0-NAxEBuAFAwAnmACmhCHAC8hKBiy4APEhjAYlPQC4zIThQiUrTKMGkA%20Xn8tXQMAIXkTV0wcMBs4Owc9ACYXVHN3Km8KPyl-NSDNEP04CIAvKNQjAB9SyL0ADxg9UgATBmjLOL9%20PSg4AFVAgH5RCABrUTgXEVIJ9TgFBTgAOQB5AGkNJbhdgD1h4vDmMuTKiBq6-sbmto70i1i4UZEJqZm58YWdze3l-cOQA)

Comment: **All:** When opening the OP's playground link, beware that *initially* it'll show the same type for both results. You have to wait for the modules to stop loading, then make and undo an edit to bump it into showing the real result. Then it shows what Matthieu lists above.

Comment: Could you [edit] this code not to rely on third-party types, *or* tag it with @angular/forms?  I suspect the answer to the question comes from the definition of `FormGroup` (probably a default type argument) but I'm not particularly inclined to go hunting around installing or inspecting libraries to find out.

Comment: @jcalz Tobias, summed it up, this happens when the class has a method with conditional return type.

Comment: It's not just the conditional; any generic type with an invariant parameter will do: https://tsplay.dev/WPzzJN The only solution for `T` here would be `any`, but apparently `infer` never yields `any`, even if it's the default. Don't know why exactly though, the documentation on inference is a little sparse. Maybe @jcalz knows more about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler should normally be able to *infer* `U`. I am not sure yet what the underlying issue is but I tracked it down to the following:

The inference fails because `FormGroup` contains *methods* which have a *conditional* in their return type.

Without the conditional, inference works fine.

```
type Foo = FormGroup<{ title: string }>
type Bar = FormGroup<{ title2: string }>;

export declare class FormGroup<TControl = any> {    
    fn1(arg: TControl): TControl
//  fn2(arg: TControl): 0 extends TControl ? true : false
}

type Baz = Foo | Bar extends FormGroup<infer U> ? true : false;
//   ^? type Baz = true
```

As soon as we introduce the conditional in a return type, the inference breaks.

```
type Foo = FormGroup<{ title: string }>
type Bar = FormGroup<{ title2: string }>;

export declare class FormGroup<TControl = any> {    
    fn1(arg: TControl): TControl
    fn2(arg: TControl): 0 extends TControl ? true : false
}

type Baz = Foo | Bar extends FormGroup<infer U> ? true : false;
//   ^? type Baz = false
```

I may do some further investigation into this issue.

possibly related:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32608

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAOQMoEYUG9jApEoAuAnnKgGID2NKAvCrQE4QDiLNArnADy5SASxIAbKAC4UMEiyEgA5igC+APkLFylFACEwLRsxptOPfoJIjxAJiky5ilaoDcBYiigAPOMZIoAJlCIovqowWAwMEYmXLx8ACoAwjQgsjSihmAgZKp47hruRABmIFgAFPoKUkkpaaIAlNXJqVyiBSgA9B3FIBUsVSg1LemNKAAMHp4kUCD+UUN1KAD8pCzcqFJFYKIwUO3KbpoUqHoAXoa09AA+uvqT07NRrByx-PJFUAYAqrkrsusoTbbXaudxdYgAPT+x1u5yY-z2wAOoEgsAQyHQGGseEORC01DoF2MLzMAmEYkk0lk8iUana+NuBiYz1McQsVigtipDlpLlxkx8LD8gXCLDCIUi0RJcQWrUy2VygmI7XcJXKlSatVao1l6RVxBKfQGuoaUgmXgec0GzUWfzWGxQWx2e3cyPcDLOROujPuMytLNefHenxQP2WqwBQOdoOI4KIUNIMM9TCduwIyKAA)

Answer (score 0):

The `infer` keyword is used to narrow the type of an expression.

In the first case, the type of the expression `Foo | Bar` is the union of the types `Foo` and `Bar`.

The first type is `FormGroup<{ title: FormControl<string> }>` while the second one is `FormGroup<{ title2: FormControl<string> }>`.

Since these types aren't the same, their union is not equal to `FormGroup<infer U>`.

But this is not true in the second case, because both `Foo` and `Bar` are a subtype of `FormGroup`, for this the second case results in `ok`

Comment: `Foo | Bar` is not a naked generic type. There is no distribution here.

Comment: @TobiasS. you are right, Im gonna update my answer

Comment: @Nullndr - TobiasS. seems to demonstrate in their answer that this is incorrect, see [this example](https://tsplay.dev/WG4Aow), which contradicts the above.